# Creating Income Statement Design in Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, crystal-reports-2010

I have table of accounts.

**Note:** If Ctrl is 1, it can control another accounts

[image]

and I also have table of transactions

[image]

All I want is to display this in crystal report that will look like this:

[image]

I try to create this but everytime I put TOTAL(Title 1, Title 1-2, Title 1-3) it always appear after the Account Title

Comment: @Siva - Can you help me again?

Comment: Where are you placing account title and calculation fields? I mean in which section?

Comment: I used subreport in displaying the Title 1-2 and Title 1-3 and I display the account title in details section and I place the calculation fields in group footer section

Comment: where did you place the sub reports?

Comment: Account Title is in sub report or main report?

Comment: In the group footer section.

Comment: To the extent I see your report design.. I think you have group according to `title` so place `Account Title` in group header and summary in group footer.. If this is not your design let me know

Comment: Actually, in my MAIN REPORT first I select all the AccTitle that CTRL = 1, I display the Account Title in Detail SeCtion and I create a sub report to select all other accounts that UNDER CONTROL by the accounts in MAIN REPORT and place it in group footer section. In My Subreport I place account title in details section also and place the total in group footer section.

Comment: I tried what you said and it works, the displaying is good but I still where should I display the total of accounts ? Note: Only the accounts with CTRL field value of 1 only compute the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I feel you have complicated the report design.. You can do it without sub report aswell. Try below approach.

This solution works assuming you have linked the two tables in database expert.

1. First group the report with below formula.

   ```
   if ctrl=1
   then ctrl
   ```
2. Now again group with `ACCTitle`
3. In detail put the calculation fields of 2nd table.

`Accttitle` and `Amount` of transaction table.

1. Place `Account title` and `Amount` in `group header1`
2. Take the respective group summaries..

Let me know after trying this approach

Comment: What do you mean by this. 1. First group the report with below formula: if ctrl = 1 then ctrl? Should I need to create formula field?

Comment: yes...exactly.. It will make sure that it will group by ctrl=1

Comment: Where should I place it?

Comment: create a group with that formula

Comment: How can I calculate the total of title 1-2,1-3 and title 1?

Comment: In group footers...just insert summary in repective group footers

Comment: Are you able to achieve the requirement?

Comment: not yet... I try to put the summary in group footer but what happen is the account title is followed by its total. Like in my example above it should be Title 1-2 | Title 1-2-1, Title 1-2-2 | Total Title 1-2. And what I'm getting is Title 1-2 | Total Title 1-2 , Title 1-2-1 , Title 1-2-2.

Comment: I'm not actually group it in account title. The account title that I used above is just an example title. And I group it in Account Code.

Comment: I try what you said, but the account title is followed by its total. where should I place the total?

Comment: account title should always be in `header` and numeric values should be in `footer`... if you interchange then there will be issue... As I see in the question `Account Title` is in top of the hierarchy so place it in `page header` or `Group Header1`. In the same way if you are talking about `Total` heading then place it in second level after `Account title`.. this is just an example change it as per your requirement.. and coming to the summary values place all values in `footers`